# MVVM Pattern, ObservableObject

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Please, help me to understand one thing in the MVVM pattern:

For example, I need to display cities on a map.
In ViewModel I have ObservableCollection, that binded to a View ItemsSource.
ObservableCollection contains objects with type "City". 
Must "City"-class be inherited from ObservableObject (I use MVVM Toolkit)? Or I should create a wrapper class, inherit it from ObservableObject, in ViewModel create new wrap-objects with data from "City"-objects and add them to the collection?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your City class is in your model, and you actually need to know about changes to properties on the city object - then you should create a wrapper for it (i.e. CityViewModel). Your wrapper should listen to events that notify of any changes to the City class, and fire off the relevant Property Change notifications.

Model classes should be designed to fit with the model and should not change to suit your view -  the point of having a ViewModel in the first place is to abstract your model from your view. The model should know nothing of the View.

If the properties of your City class dont change, or you dont care if they don change (and you are not a purist) then you could just expose it directly - without inheriting ObservableObject. 
(Although I dont use MVVM toolkit, I cant see why in general you would need to inherit ObservableObject just because you are storing the City objects in an ObservableCollection).

The purist view however, is to wrap everything that you bind to and never expose anything from the model directly to the view.

Comment: Ok, I see. It seems I misunderstood the pattern. It looks like model hasn't any logic (i.e. loading data from database), it just contains data, right? But, as you say (purist view), every model class, that bind to View, must be wrapped by ViewModel class and it appears that there will be a lot of ViewModel and one View or just one ViewModel can wrap all model classes?

Comment: @Shallow -  what do you mean by wrapping. Your view is binded to viewmodel and viewmodel has model(s) in it.

Comment: The model in MVVM includes all of the business logic parts of your application. This includes the objects that hold data, as well as the objects that get that data, talk to services, or perform any other business functions. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff798279.aspx which gives some general info, and http://blog.alner.net/archive/2010/02/09/mvvm-to-wrap-or-not-to-wrap.aspx which pretty much answers your question.

Comment: OK, thank you. So, for example, if I need to convert latitude and longitude properties to X, Y (pixels), that used only for drawing, I should create ViewModel for "City"-class. Also I still have MainViewModel that contains ObservableCollection with cities to display all cities. Right? Simple, I use classes from other projects and try to minimize modifying of them.

Answer (score 1):

ObservableCollection or ObservableObject has no relation with MVVM model. You can create a MVVM based application without ObservableCollection and ObservableObject (ObservableObject are used when you need to change the values of property of your class but if your application is readonly you dont even need it).

MVVM -
M-Model (business layer) , V-View (GUI), ViewModel- (Context of GUI).

When XAML works on binding. You must need a notification mechanism to notify GUI that something is changed. Now if a collection is changed means you added or removed an item from collection, you need to raise a notification which you dont need if you are working with ObservableCollection. Similarly, if your class City has a property Population which when changes need to notify GUI, that's why need to make an ObservableObject.

Hope it helps..